# Twitters strange choice of markup

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup

Viewing the Twitter source and i came across this. Strange to see an '`a`' element without a `href` attribute. When the user clicks the link, all that happens is a pop up appears, it doesn't go to a different page, a la normal hyperlinks. Are they gaining any semantic kudos by using an '`a`' element without a `href` or is this very very bad markup? Why would they not just use the `span` with an id?

```
<a id="new-tweet" original-title="New Tweet">
      <span>New Tweet</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anchor is giving them the click appearance without having to style it in (e.g. `cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;`). It also allows them to make a more uniform feel across the page, instead of styling the "normal links" and ajax links separately.

A's can be used without a `href` attribute (they used to be used to reference sections of a page (combined with the name attribute, then link.html#name) before IDs started being the more definitive way to reference portions of a page).

I would say they're just keeping it "slim and trim".

Comment: Ah, fits in with their 140 character limit then :)

Comment: And of course, using `a` instead of `span` saves 6 characters per tweet. It all adds up when you are twitter scale.